# What are the symptoms of a bad complete strut assembly on a 2009 Honda Civic LX

Tags: honda, civic, vibration, struts

What are the symptoms of a bad complete strut assembly on a 2009 Honda Civic LX . I've got an undiagnosable vibration

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Usually a bad strut will not cause a vibration. Symptoms of a bad strut is the car may lean if the spring is broke, if the shock in it is bad then it will not be smooth over bumps and can cause delayed suspension rebound if really bad.